# Are limits on exponents in moduli possible?

Tags: number-theory, limits, irrational-numbers, exponentiation

Suppose I show that:
$$x^{f(z)/g(z)} = y \pmod{4}$$
is impossible for some given positive integers $x$ and $y$, where,
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \phi(4)  k_1(z) + 1 \\
&= 2 k_1(z) + 1\\
g(z) &= \phi(4) k_2(z) + 1 \\
&= 2  k_2(z) + 1
\end{align*}
and $k_1(z)$ and $k_2(z)$ are integer functions, that approach infinity, such that $f(z)/g(z)$ approaches some irrational number. Can I then say, the equation:
$$x^{f(z)/g(z)} = y$$
has no solutions integer solutions, with the same $x$ and $y$, as $z$ goes to infinity as well?

That is, if I let,
$$d = \lim_{z->\infty}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$$
be the irrational number in the limit, then would it be true that,
$$x^d \neq y$$
for the same $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: Thanks to whoever formatted my equations.  I'm still trying to figure out math notations.

Comment: That $x^d=y$ has no solutions with $x$ an integer, $x\neq 0,1$, $d$ irrational, and $y$ *algebraic* (in particular, for $y$ integer) follows from the Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

Comment: Doesn't the Gelfond-Schneider theorem refer to x^y != d by your definitions, rather than x^d = y?  I mean, if we assume y is relatively prime to x, certainly d would have to be irrational, right?

Comment: Sorry; you'd need $d$ to be algebraic, not just irrational, to apply Gelfond-Schneider. My mistake.

Comment: No problem, other than the fact that we're back at square one, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is negative, you can't derive $x^d \ne y $ from $x^{f(n)/g(n)}\not \equiv y \pmod{4} $ for every $n$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to d $$
Look at this example
$$ x= 2, y = 3, d = \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} $$
as $d$ is irrational (see Hardy and Wright p. 162), we can find rational numbers $f(n)/g(n)$ with odd numerator and denominator that converge to $d$, (for example if $n$ is odd and
  $$ \frac{a_n}{n} < \frac{\log 3}{\log 2} < \frac{a_n+1}{n} $$
then pick $g(n) = n$ and $f(n) = a_n$ if $a$ is odd or $f(n)=a_n+1$ otherwise).

We have obviously 
$$ 2^{f(n)} \not\equiv 3^{g(n)} \pmod{4} $$
because the left hand side is even and the right hand side is odd however
$$ 2^d = 3$$

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I see it now.  Thank you!  On a closely related note, do you know if there is any way to express the limit in the modulus, such that it does correspond to the equation?

Comment: To define limits in modular equations you need a topology, I think that what you are lookimg is $p$-adic analysis. But even with a proposition like $\lim x^{f(n)/g(N)} \ne y$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (if that can be properly defined) for every $p$ I'm not sure if you could derive that $x^d \ne y$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I really wonder about mod p for some prime p.